# Multiline bash command in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

I have the following sh command in my Jenkinsfile which does not work because it tries to execute the last "DATA" as a command.
If I move last "DATA" to the beginning of the line it works but is not as beautiful as I want. 
Is there a way to the indention in this case?

```
    sh """
        sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no appsadm@$backup_registry <<DATA
        sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop || true
        sudo yum remove -y docker-engine.x86_64
        sudo rm -fr /var/lib/docker /var/log/docker
        sudo rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm || true
        sudo yum update -y
        sudo yum -y install docker-io
        sudo sed -i 's#other_args=.*#other_args="--insecure-registry $official_registry:5000"#g' /etc/sysconfig/docker
        sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
        DATA
        """
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `<<DATA` specifies the end of here-doc `<<-DATA` suppress leading tabs but not spaces

```
cat <<-DATA
    hello
<tab>DATA
```

another option is to add spaces in marker

```
cat << "    DATA"
    hello
    DATA
```

Comment: won't the second option mean that variables in the multi-line string won't be interpreted?

Comment: the commands just demonstrate how heredoc works. How the content is interpreted depends on the program which reads input here `cat` will dysplay the content; in your question will be executed by a shell through ssh and sshpass.

Comment: how would you remove spaces as well, not just tabs?

Answer (score 24):

I know this is an old question, but I had ran into this at some point, and eventually ended up using stripIndent()

```
steps {
    echo 'Deploying....'
    sh """
    ssh somewhere <<EOF
    cd somewhere
    do some more stuff
    EOF
    """.stripIndent()
}
```

That way you can still keep your indentations and formatting

Comment: It is strange.  I saw this yesterday and liked the "elegance" of it.  However, it didn't work for me.  In my case, the `ssh somewhere` and `delimiter` did align by spaces, but the pipeline didn't see the `EOF` properly: even when I used `<<EOF`.  I don't know Groovy, could there be a difference in the use of `stripIndent()` inside of a `script` block as opposed to the `steps` you have?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** We don't need to use EOF, simply put the semicolon at the end of statement on multiline shell script as shown below

```
sh """ if [ -d /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.38/webapps/ROOT ] ;
       then ;
            ssh $USERNAME@$DEV_HOSTNAME 'sudo rm -rf /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.38/webapps/ROOT' ;
            echo 'ROOT directory deleted successfully' ;
       fi ;
"""
```